# show only sub categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to show the category thumb and description of custom taxonomy. lets say I have this:

```
<ul>
<li>Cars
  <ul>
     <li>Electric cars</li>
     <li>foo cars
         <ul>
            <li>Toyota</li>
            <li>Nissan</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And what i need is to show the thumb and description of the subcategories **electric cars** and **foo cars**, not the post inside them.

Anyone can guide me, where i can looking foor?

Tks

Comment: you could look at [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to get an array of categories (use the _taxonomy_ argument to specify your taxonomy) or use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) to get an html list

Comment: For truly custom representation you should take a look at extending the walker class (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class), there are various tutorials about this around the web.